# Differences in Fallout 3 between Xbox 360 and PC

Tags: fallout-3

I'm finally getting around to playing Fallout 3, and I heard there were differences between the PC version and the Xbox 360 version. Half of my friends have played the Xbox 360 version, and half the PC, but no one I know has played both. If I were to play Steam Fallout 3, I'd get achievements, right?

So what, if any, are the major the differences in plot, graphics, gameplay, expansions?

Comment: You can't use the console in the xbox version, which means you have less options to deal with potentially game-breaking bugs.

Comment: Do you mean Steam achievements? If so, I'm afraid you only get the MS achievements on your MS account on the PC too.

Comment: @Stuart Pegg so the achievements you get via steam in fallout 3 are the same as the ones you get on the xbox? or different?

Comment: Good question. I suppose just because the account they're recorded on is the same doesn't mean the achievements can't be platform-specific.

Comment: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_achievements_and_trophies "Despite both the PC and Xbox having identical achievements, the game has separate IDs for the two on LIVE which makes cross-platform profile comparison not possible."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding plot, gameplay and expansions Fallout 3 is exactly the same on all platforms (PC, XBox 360 and PS3).

The differences in the PC version are the ability to do more precise tunings on graphic setttings, the possibility to enable the developer console and the huge advantage that you can install many MODs developed by community.

MODs are modifications to the original game created by community members.

Fallout 3 in particular is easily moddable and for this reason the community created hundreds of different mods and modifications that change every aspect of the game:

- Graphics (better textures, dynamic weather, object re-skins, NPC 3D models and faces etc.)
- Gameplay (hardcore modes, balance fixes, etc.)
- Sounds

or add original contents like new armors, weapons, buildings or even complete new quests.

I suggest you to visit the amazing [Fallout 3 Nexus](http://www.fallout3nexus.com) website that has a huge database of mods and patches and it is the reference site for many Fallout 3 modders.

Comment: +1 for the mods, the community has released some great content.

Comment: MODS? tell me more...

Comment: @LoveMeSomeCode I updated my answer with more info.

Comment: ha, I know WHAT a mod is. I was meaning, 'i didn't know there were mods for this game. what sorts of mods are available.' but, good link

Comment: @LoveMeSomeCode There are so many mods that is difficult to suggest you which you could like, depends also on what you are looking for: better graphic, different gameplay or new missions. I am sure you will find a lot of interesting mod in that site.

Comment: +1 for mods. Thank you for giving me the incentive to drag my guy the rest of the way through Mothership-oh-my-god-I'm-sick-of-linear-gameplay-Zeta. Please feel free to add the achievement info I commented above if you feel it'd add value.